# How to invalidate cache for JS file loaded from bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, caching, browser-cache, bookmarklet

I have a bookmarklet that looks like this:

```
javascript:(function(){var a=document.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript";a.src="//example.com/script.min.js";a.charset="utf-8";document.body.appendChild(a)})();
```

I have the following in my `.htaccess` file to allow files to be cached:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    # Enable expirations
    ExpiresActive On
    # Default directive
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
    # My favicon
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    # Images
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    # CSS
    ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
    # Javascript
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

The problem is that sometimes I make changes to `script.js` and I want people using the bookmarklet to get the updated file to prevent problems.

For files loaded on my website, I overcome this issue by versioning the files, but I don't see how I could do that with the bookmarklet.

Comment: Have you checked this way `a.src="//example.com/script.min.js?v="+(Math.random());`

Comment: @hex494D49 The problem is, that would force the users to download the file every time (it wouldn't allow them to cache the file at all).

Comment: Well, I hope the file isn't huge :) I don't see another solution. I use this as well. Actually, as far as I know the bookmarklet shouldn't be larger/longer than 3000 characters, but not sure at this moment.

Comment: Or, maybe this way. Check the version of the bookmarklet onload and add the tip from my first comment. Something like `var new_version = "http://my-domain/version/"; if(new_version > current_version) a.src = "..."+(Math.random()`

Comment: @hex494D49 That would require users to manually update their bookmarklet each time I changed the JS file, though, which isn't feasible.

Comment: I just wrote a bookmarklet a few days ago and tried this tip - getting a value from my server. Only I put this in my listener file `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] . "");`

Comment: Of course, I used ajax request to get that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly there is no way for the client to magically know that you have updated the script unless it checks the server.

So with that fact established you simply must decide how to balance the cost of checking your server vs what amount of delay is acceptable, and consider that together with the amount of effort you wish to put into solving the problem.

The easiest solution IMHO is to simply change the cache time to a day or two.

Also, look up "http etag". If done right, the client will check the server each time, but the amount of data being transmitted should be trivial.

If you don't want to change your mod_expires rules universally for all ".js" files, there is nothing in the world that says you have to use ".js" as the extension for all script files. The client doesn't care.

Another solution is to append a date string like "?dt=2014-07-31-01:00:32" to the script file, but you can craft the date string to force a fresh download once per day, or every couple of days, or once per week, or month, or whatever.